# Folium - how to call get_bounds() on the visible panned map

Tags: python, folium

I'm running the code below on Jupyter Notebook

```
import folium
from folium import features

%matplotlib inline

lat_lon= [35.8984,14.5131]

fg=folium.FeatureGroup(name="Test FeatureGroup")
fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=lat_lon, tooltip="Test Tooltip"))

m = folium.Map(lat_lon, zoom_start=16)

m.add_child(fg)
m.add_child(folium.LayerControl())

print(m.get_bounds())

m
```

If I pan the map and visit another town, and then call **print(m.get_bounds())**  I get the same original co-ordinates which do not reflect the current visible map.

Is there a way to call get.bounds() on the visible map?

Answer (score 1):

I had this question too, but it seems unfortunately this can't be done from within the folium Package itself. See this discussion thread by the devs: https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1118